# Chrome cursor alternates between arrow and pointer over links, dev tools flashes

Tags: google-chrome, cursor, google-chrome-devtools, flashing

I am having the strangest behavior in Chrome and its slowing efficiency in development.  For some reason hovering over any link will cause my mouse cursor to start flashing alternating between the arrow and the hand pointer.

Also opening dev tools you see content flashing, specifically on the 'styles' you'll see two sets of styles flashing alternating between one another.

I have written Google about it, researched endlessly still having not found any solution other than it being a problem will Mozilla on a PC a few years ago, which I don't use either. PLEASE if anyone has experienced this I am COMPLETELY clueless as to what might be causing this.

I have disabled all extensions, reset and restarted countless times, Incognito doesn't work (I should have to use Incognito to operate efficiently in Chrome anyways) still nothing has helped.